# Android ENOENT warning

Tags: android, uri, android-mediaplayer, fileinputstream

I am new to android trying to make a custom video controller from an opensource snippet, i have added comments where i thought were necessary for understanding the code a little better, hope it will be helpfull

```
    public void playVideo(){
    if(videoview.isPlaying()){
        videoview.stopPlayback();
    }
    try {
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        File file = new File(path);//path is a string
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);//log says warning is here
        player.setDataSource(inputStream.getFD());
        inputStream.close();
        player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: How did you generate the `path` string?

Comment: path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video1;

Comment: where path is of type string

Comment: Then shouldn't you be using `new File(Uri.parse(path))` ?

Comment: I had previously done this: "File file = new File(Uri.parse(path));" but it said "The constructor File(Uri) is undefined"

Comment: Oh, right. The `File` constructor takes an `URI`, not an `Uri`. You might want to look into `openRawResourceFd` (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3603165/1524450).

Comment: @Michael after going through documentation for setDataSource i found out there is another constructor using uri, sorry for not understanding your answer in the begining..... and btw how do I +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an `InputStream` for a raw resource, use [`openRawResource(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource%28int%29).

Possibly you could also use [`MediaPlayer.create(Context,int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20int%29) to directly create a `MediaPlayer` with a given resource identifier.