# Play audio on touch - Android

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

In my app, i want to play sound when a user is moving a tile, i added the following code --

```
private void moveTile(Tile tile, Cell cell) {
        grid.field[tile.getX()][tile.getY()] = null;
        grid.field[cell.getX()][cell.getY()] = tile;
        tile.updatePosition(cell);

        MediaPlayer mp = null;
        if(mp!=null) {
            mp.release();
        }
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(mContext,R.raw.movetile);
        mp.start();
    }
```

But whenever i am moving the first tile, the app is not responding, its not crashing also, any help.

Comment: You might like https://stackoverflow.com/q/2969242/3166697 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/18254870/3166697

Comment: did you debug from above media player code is working? also cross check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) In your code, the `if(mp!=null) {mp.release();}` should be moved above `MediaPlayer mp = null;`. Otherwise, it has no purpose (because the condition is always false).

2) Make sure `tile.updatePosition(cell)` is not the one causing your app to be non-responding.

3) Try this approach instead, it should work:

```
static MediaPlayer mp = null;

// ...

private void moveTile(Tile tile, Cell cell) {
        grid.field[tile.getX()][tile.getY()] = null;
        grid.field[cell.getX()][cell.getY()] = tile;
        tile.updatePosition(cell);

        try
        {
            if (mp != null)
            {
                if (mp.isPlaying ())
                    mp.stop ();

                mp.reset ();
                mp.release ();
                mp = null;
            }

            mp = MediaPlayer.create (getApplicationContext (), R.raw.movetile);

            if (mp != null)
            {
                mp.start ();
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle the error ...
            }

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Handle the error ...
        }
}
```

Comment: ya i voted up but due to my lower reputation level its not taking the vote up.